# why gmail receive my email in spam folder and how can i solve it?

Tags: gmail, spam, spf, dkim, dmarc

I am really confused. Gmail still puts my emails into spam folder.
I have DMARC, DKIM and SPF records, all valid.[this is image from gmail message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTR7N.png)

please tell me why all of email in my domain  received as spam and how can i solve it

Comment: Unfortunately this is business as usual for gmail. Their spam filtering is terrible. Check your reputation on https://postmaster.google.com, but don't expect to be able to do much about it.

Comment: its  shows  to me this " No data to display at this time. Please come back later.
Postmaster Tools requires that your domain satisfies certain conditions before data is visible for this chart. Refer to the help page for more details.   "

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Synchro said, gmail's spam filters can be overzealous at times, but there are a few things you can do to help.

It looks like you've already done the necessary technical things (SPF, DKIM, DMARC, etc)

However, did you consider the subject and the contents of your message?

Your subject line alone says very little, and if it's a very generic email, google may see it as spam, try including the person's name, if possible

Assuming, for example, this is to request an interview with someone
Eg:

Instead of "interview", you could write

", are you interested in interviewing?"

Then in the body include the user's name as well, all of these will make your message look less like generic spam, and more like an email the person is expecting or requested, lowering the probability it'll go to spam.

Until your domain gets a reputation with google as probably not spam, they tend to lean that direction.

Also ensure all automated emails you send have an unsubscribe link etc

Comment: thank you for your replay but all servers receive my email in spam folder and when i make email  test from webmail  will  be spam too